# Roslyn code analyzers - when should I use "this."?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, c#-6.0, roslyn-code-analysis

I've always been explicit with my code when using instance members, prefixing them with `this.` and with static members, prefixing them with the type name.

Roslyn seems not to like this, and politely suggests that you can omit `this.` and `Type.` from your code where appropriate...

...so where I would do **this.**.. *(no pun intended)*

```
public void DoSomethingCool()
{
    this.CallAwesomeMethod();
    CoolCucumber.DoSomethingLessAewsome();
}
```

...roslyn suggests I do this...

```
public void DoSomethingCool()
{
    CallAwesomeMethod();
    DoSomethingLessAwesome();
}
```

...however when it comes to using extension methods, it appears that I cannot omit the use of `this.` for example...

```
public int GetTotal()
{
    // This doesn't work    
    return Sum(o => o.Value);

    // This does
    return this.Sum(o => o.Value);
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Why does Roslyn not seem to like explicit use of `this.` and `Type.` ?
2. Why do I need to explicitly use `this.` for extension methods?
3. Whilst not strictly part of this question, how do I resolve the discrepancy between Roslyn NOT wanting me to use `this.` and `Type.` and StyleCop's analyzers insisting that I use them?

Comment: Roslyn is just brain-dead about not liking you to use this.  I suppose the Roslyn team members don't need IntelliSense, smart programmers they are.  But given the quality of the product, they perhaps ought to have used it a bit more.  Knowing when to tune-out the lightbulb is up to you, we can't help you with that.  Fwiw, somebody else was asleep when they picked an icon with a bright background for a dark color scheme.  Fit and finish is plain inadequate, it is going to take time.

Comment: @HansPassant: This check can easily be disabled in Options.

Comment: @SLaks I noticed a .ruleset file in my project which contained all of the Roslyn and Stylecop rules for a project: I stuck with StyleCop's recommendation rather than using Roslyn

Comment: There are actually issues possible with omitting `this` on extension methods in somewhat exotic situations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27884101/1864167

Comment: Also note that ReSharper thinks `this` should typically be omitted as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct on this behavior. It has struck me too when using Visual Studio 2015 and I wondered the same as you did. Here are my thoughts on this:

1. Why does Roslyn not seem to like explicit use of `this.` and `Type.`?

   It is overhead, and it seems it wants to minimize the code needed. I prefer being explicit in my code though. It is much easier to understand the scope of a variable without having knowing the rest of the code. (*Maybe* it is also a marketing strategy to let us know about the code analyzers... Or am I thinking  too much)
2. Why do I need to explicitly use `this.` for extension methods?

   I guess this is the rule to supply the first parameter of the extension method, the `this`. Without providing `this` it doesn't know the context to call the method on. Actually, the extension method `this.Sum(x => x)` is actually rewritten as `Enumerable.Sum(this, x => x)`. See the 'need' for `this`? I guess omitting this is technically possible, but I prefer to be explicit in this case too and I am glad the compiler does too.

Answer (score 1):

`this.` is a syntax that is provided in C# to *resolve ambiguity*. For example:

```
class Square
{
    private int size;

    public Square(int size)
    {
        size = size;      // How do we differentiate member and parameter?
    }
}
```

So **using `this.` to be explicit** is rather an oxymoron, because it is solving a problem caused by a **lack** of explicitness.

The 'best practice' I would recommend is to write code that is not ambiguous in the first place, thus eliminating the need to use `this.`. Ambiguity is not only disliked by the compiler but it can be extremely confusing for other programmers trying to read your code.

To achieve disambiguation we need to use different names for things like member variables and parameters. The most common approach (apart from `this.`) is to use naming prefixes to identify members. Many programmers dislike prefixes but this is usually because they have never seen/used a well designed prefix system - I've described my approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228161/why-use-prefixes-on-member-variables-in-c-classes/1229360#1229360), and once you get used to it, it is a very powerful way of communicating useful information to yourself and your teammates, and eliminating several common types of bugs caused by ambiguity and mixups.

Comment: I rather like your linked approach.  One thing though, what do you do for a member level pointer?  mpTarget or pmTarget?  Do you have a preferred 'pattern' to 'stack' prefixese?

Comment: Thanks! I guess my conventional ordering boils down to the "special modifiers" (member/static/volatile) and then "usage information" (pointer, event), which results in "mp" ordering. As static/volatile/event are usually members I tend to use "s" rather than "ms" to keep things cleaner, so for me it's usually only in C/C++ (where prefixes "mp" or "pp" crop up) that they end up being more than 1 character long.