# Cannot use LINQ methods on IEnumerable base class from derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, ienumerator

I am trying to implement `IEnumerable<Turtle>` in a class deriving from a base class that already implements `IEnumerable<Animal>`.

Why will calling `base.Cast<Turtle>()` (or any LINQ method on the base element) in any method from the class `Turtle` fail to compile?

It is not possible to replace `base` with `this` as it obviously results in a `StackOverflowException`.

Here is a minimal code sample to replicate the issue:

```
public interface IAnimal {}

public class Animal : IAnimal {}

public class Turtle : Animal {}

public class AnimalEnumerable : IEnumerable<Animal> {
    List<Animal> Animals = new List<Animal>();
    IEnumerator<Animal> IEnumerable<Animal>.GetEnumerator() {
        return Animals.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return Animals.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class TurtleEnumerable : AnimalEnumerable, IEnumerable<Turtle> {
    IEnumerator<Turtle> IEnumerable<Turtle>.GetEnumerator() {
        return base.Cast<Turtle>().GetEnumerator(); //FAILS WITH "CANNOT RESOLVE SYMBOL Cast"
    }
}
```

For some reason, replacing `base.Cast<Turtle>().GetEnumerator();` with `this.OfType<Animal>().Cast<Turtle>().GetEnumerator();` works without throwing a `StackOverflowException`, but I have no idea why.

Comment: How is that supposed to work? These are different classes - TurtleEnumerable does not inherit from Turtle in any way, it just implements the interface IEnumerable<Turtle>

Comment: TurtleEnumerable does inherit from the class AnimalEnumerable, so it should have access to base elements.

Comment: Something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883427/why-cant-i-call-an-extension-method-from-a-base-class-of-the-extended-type

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are numerous problems with the code given that other answers get into. I want to answer your specific question:

> Why will calling `base.Cast<Turtle>()` (or any LINQ method on the base element) in any method from the class `Turtle` fail to compile?

Let's go to the specification, section 7.6.8.

> A base-access is used to access base class members that are hidden by similarly named members in the current class or struct.

Are you accessing a base class member?  **NO**. An extension method is a member of the static class that contains the extension method, not the base class.

> A base-access is permitted only in the block of an instance constructor, an instance method, or an instance accessor.

You're fine here.

> When base.I occurs in a class or struct, I must denote a member of the base class of that class or struct.

Again, `Cast<T>` is not a member of the base class.

> When a base-access references a virtual function member (a method, property, or indexer), the determination of which function member to invoke at run-time (§7.5.4) is changed.

You are not accessing a virtual anything. Extension methods are static.

> The function member that is invoked is determined by finding the most derived implementation of the function member with respect to B (instead of with respect to the run-time type of this, as would be usual in a non-base access). Thus, within an override of a virtual function member, a base-access can be used to invoke the inherited implementation of the function member.

So now we see what the purpose of a base access is:  **to enable a non-virtual dispatch to a virtual member that was overriden in the current type**, or **to call a base class member that was hidden by a `new` member in the current type**.  That is not what you are trying to use `base` for, and therefore you are doomed to failure. Stop using `base` off-label like this. Only use it when attempting to do a non-virtual dispatch to a virtual member, or get access to a hidden member.

Answer (score 5):

Eric Lippert has stated before that this was a somewhat conscious design decision [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510964/why-is-the-this-keyword-required-to-call-an-extension-method-from-within-the-e). You were never meant to use extension methods in a case where you have access to the implementation of your base class in the first place.

And if you think about it, you also dont need to do this here. Make a GetEnumerator property or method that is protected and use it! Basic object orientation; no need to torture linq here.

**EDIT:**
It was pointed out that my previous suggestion did not work. So let me suggest just not implementing two different IEnumerable interfaces as this will cause a lot of headaches with foreach anyway.

I have come to believe that this implementation might be what you actually want:

```
public interface IAnimal { }

public class Animal : IAnimal { }

public class Turtle : Animal { }

public class AnimalEnumerable : IEnumerable<Animal>
{
    IEnumerator<Animal> IEnumerable<Animal>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class TurtleEnumerable : AnimalEnumerable
{
}
```

You can then enumerate through `Animal` and their derivatives all the like

Comment: You cannot cast `IEnumerator<Animal>` to `IEnumerator<Turtle>` so this code wont compile.

Comment: You'd have to create a protected method in the base class that returns a IEnumerable for use by the derived class.

Comment: I ended up just exposing `List<Animal> Animals` in a protected fashion so that I can call `this.Animals.Cast<Turtle>().GetIterator()` from the `Turtle` class.

Comment: May I ask why you need the XYZEnumerable classes at all? Why not just make IAnimal implement IEnumerable and be done with it. Then you can enumerate throught Animal and Turtle all you want via the interface

Comment: I am in a rather complex case of interface composition, in my actual use case there are actually other interfaces involved. Everything could probably be refactored to avoid this, but for now I had to find a working solution.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer to that question:

> Why will calling base.Cast() (or any LINQ method on the base
>   element) in any method from the class Turtle fail to compile?

The reason of that exception is `Cast` and other such methods are ***extension methods***. And extension methods are static.

For example, let's look at that:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Method2(this Base b) ...
}

public class Base 
{
    public void Method1() ...
}

public class Derived:Base
{
    public void Test()
    {
        base.Method1();

        base.Method2(); // Does not contain a definition
    }
}
```

And as you know extension methods are a really nice syntactic sugar. They're not really added to the class, but the compiler makes it feel like they are. So, compiler will change that line of code to that one:

```
 Extensions.Method2(base);
```

If you replace your code with that one the compiler will give more appropriate error message: **Use of keyword `base` is not valid in this context.**

As said in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx):

> A base class access is permitted only in a constructor, an instance
>   method, or an instance property accessor.

Comment: Why wouldn't extension methods be callable using the base keyword? Are you aware of a workaround to access base elements (apart from the ugly `this.OfType<Animal>().Cast<Turtle>().GetEnumerator();`)?

Comment: You cannot call `base` from a static method to access the iterator and elements.

Comment: @ErwinMayer Sorry, I was in a hurry. I will try to explain it more depply.

Comment: Makes sense. If I have to use `this` instead, how can I then achieve what I want?

Comment: @ErwinMayer The best way is to create instance method in base class, and then use it. Don't use the extension methods of the base class.

Comment: I upvoted you because you provided a good explanation why `base` cannot be used for my purpose. I have good reasons to implement IEnumerable twice in my case so the first part of your answer is not very relevant and could be a reason why some people downvoted you.

Comment: @ErwinMayer Thanks, actually I have added the first part 5-10 minutes ago. But, I don't know why my answer downvoted 2 times. May be I have answered only a part of your question.

Comment: I think you also got downvoted when your answer contained mistakes (initially), some people do not assume you are going to fix them...

Comment: @ErwinMayer May be :) Thanks. for trying to explain. Actually I have never came across this error message, so it took my time to make my answer better. No problem, I am happy that today I have learned more things.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your approach. `TurtleEnumerable` implements both `IEnumerable<Animal>` and `IEnumerable<Turtle>`. To be able to use a `TurtleEnumerable` instance in a `foreach` loop you will have to cast it for the code to compile:

```
foreach (var turtle in (IEnumerable<Turtle>) turtleEnumerable)
```

You are also using explicit interface implementations to hide the generic `GetEnumerator()` methods. You have to do that because you cannot do overload resolution on return type alone and the two generic `GetEnumerator()` methods only differ by return type.

However, this means that a `TurtleEnumerable` method cannot call the base `GetEnumerator()` method. The reason for this is that `base` does not behave like a variable of type "base". Instead it is a reserved word that only can be used to call base class methods. A corollary to this is that extension methods cannot be used with `base`. Also, you cannot cast `base` so explicit interface implementations on the base class are not callable through `base`.

However, you can cast `this` but because the generic `GetEnumerator()` on `TurtleEnumerable` hides the generic `GetEnumerator()` on `AnimalEnumerable` you will not be able to call into the base class so you will get a stack overflow because at some point the implementation of `TurtleEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` will call the same `GetEnumerator`.

To make your code compile you need to create a `protected IEnumerator<Animal> GetEnumerator()` method in your base class and create your own `TurtleEnumerator` class that wraps the base enumerator instance you can get by calling the protected method.

```
public class TurtleEnumerable : AnimalEnumerable, IEnumerable<Turtle> {

  IEnumerator<Turtle> IEnumerable<Turtle>.GetEnumerator() {
    return new TurtleEnumerator(base.GetEnumerator());
  }

  sealed class TurtleEnumerator : IEnumerator<Turtle> {

    IEnumerator<Animal> animalEnumerator;

    public TurtleEnumerator(IEnumerator<Animal> animalEnumerator) {
      this.animalEnumerator = animalEnumerator;
    }

    public Turtle Current {
      get { return (Turtle) animalEnumerator.Current; }
    }

    Object IEnumerator.Current {
      get { return Current; }
    }

    public Boolean MoveNext() {
      return animalEnumerator.MoveNext();
    }

    public void Reset() {
      animalEnumerator.Reset();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
      animalEnumerator.Dispose();
    }

  }

}
```

All in all having a collection the implements both `IEnumerable<Base>` and `IEnumerable<Derived>` will get you into a lot of trouble. What are you trying to achieve by using this design?

Using a generic `List<T>` and contravariance you can do things like this:

```
IEnumerable<Turtle> turtles = new List<Turtle>();
IEnumerable<Animal> animals = (IEnumerable<Animal>) turtles;
```

You can also replace `List<T>` by your own generic collection type if that is required.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you implementing the IEnumerable on the TurtleEnumerator class? Also, I don't think the accessibility on the AnimalEnumerable when you implemented the IEnumerable interface is correct.

Wouldn't it be implemented something like this:

```
    public interface IAnimal { }

    public class Animal : IAnimal { }

    public class Turtle : Animal { }

    public class AnimalEnumerable : IEnumerable<Animal>
    {
        protected List<Animal> Animals = new List<Animal>();

        public IEnumerator<Animal> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return Animals.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return Animals.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    public class TurtleEnumerable : AnimalEnumerable
    {
        public void AddTurtle(Turtle turtle)
        {
            Animals.Add(turtle);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Turtle> GetTurtles()
        {
            var iterator = GetEnumerator();

            yield return iterator.Current as Turtle;
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void CanAddTurtles()
    {
        Turtle one = new Turtle();
        Turtle two = new Turtle();

        TurtleEnumerable turtleStore = new TurtleEnumerable();

        turtleStore.AddTurtle(one);
        turtleStore.AddTurtle(two);

        foreach (var turtle in turtleStore.GetTurtles())
        {
            // Do something with the turtles....
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have good reasons to need to implement two interfaces which both implement IEnumerable. The example I used is only a simplification. 

However I ended up just exposing `List<Animal> Animals` in a protected fashion so that I can call `this.Animals.Cast<Turtle>().GetIterator()` from the `Turtle` class.